# 2-Dimensional Fast Fourier Transform 3-D plot in Matlab

Tags: matlab

We want to plot in Matlab using mesh function the FFT2 of an image (we have applied `fftshift`, `abs`, and `log`).

So how do we do that?

```
imageB=imread('pic2', 'jpg');

figure, imshow(imageB)

fftB=fft2(double(imageB));

F1=fftshift(fftB);

F2=abs(F1);

F3=log(F2+1);

mesh(F3)
```

We want a 3-D plot of the FFT.

Comment: Please provide code to see where you're at.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

An option using `surf`:

```
imageB=rgb2gray(imread('http://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/d/db/Patern_test.jpg'));
```

Note that the original image is a RGB image, thus the FFT will also be a 3-channel array. Either convert to grayscale or access one channel with `F1(:,:,1)`

```
fftB=fft2(double(imageB));
F1=log(abs(fftshift(fftB)));

surf(F1), shading flat;
```

Result:

[image]